# Spring Batch - How to handle an object buffering on the ItemProcessor's level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, etl

I am using a Spring Batch under the hood in my application.
I have a lot of the already written ItemReader(s), ItemWriter(s) and a composite ItemProcessor(s) that allow me to build a Job that contains a chunk steps. All of the components share the same domain object "Product".

```
public class CustomReader implements ItemReader<Product> {

@Override
public Product read() throws Exception {
    //business logic for reading a products
    return null;
 }
}



public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<Product> {

@Override
public void write(List<? extends Product> items) throws Exception {
    //business logic for writing a products
  }
}


public class CustomProcessor extends ItemProcessor<Product, Product> {

@Override
public Product process(Product product) throws Exception {
    //custom logic for data processing
    return null;
 }
}
```

Currently I need to have a possibility to use a new ItemProcessor that will be sending an http requests. However, from the Processor's perspective I have an access only to the individual Product object, but instead of sending an http request for a single product, I need to gather a 10 products together (get their ids) and execute a batch request. Then I need to map the response and return a multiple Products back to the ItemWriter.

```
public class CustomHttpProcessor extends ItemProcessor<Product, Product> {
@Override
public List<Product> process(List<Product> product) throws Exception {
    //custom logic for sending a batch requests via http
    return null;
 }
}
```

Is there any other option than changing the base domain object from Product to List everywhere in the codebase (I have a feeling that I will significantly decrease the performance of the entire application and skyrocket the memory usage?) Are there any other Spring Batch's features that I can use, or any patterns that I can use?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an `ItemWriteListener#beforeWrite(Chunk<Product> products)`. This callback gives you access to the chunk or items just before they are written, so you can perform your REST batch request at that point and transform them as needed before the `write` operation.