# Spring batch process large date at one time

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We need to read list of data from database and after that process this list and after that send this list to third party
We need to send as list not one object how I can do that using spring batch I found processor can handle one by one not list

Comment: You did not share enough details to understand what you are trying to achieve, but from the description I guess this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605755/spring-batch-how-to-handle-an-object-buffering-on-the-itemprocessors-level

Answer (score 1):

> I found processor can handle one by one not list

ItemProcessor class is only for one record and exactly the place where you will implement your processing of list elements. For example calculating something or enhancing with additional data.

But Spring Batch framework is for lists of such records. So don't worry - you are on the right path. Just read some more tutorials and docu about it, like here:
[spring.io/batch](https://spring.io/batch)